# Error in Running Server using python with django framework

Tags: django, django-models, python-3.6

I'm a beginner in programming and my first project is creating a website using python with django framework as the back-end.However on trying to run the server. I was getting the following error. So can someone please explain?

```
   (myvenv) C:\Users\Rohan Jain\venvi>python manage.py runserver
    Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x000001FACC183378>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-  packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\venvi\mysite\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined
```

Comment: You did not import include in your urls.py. import this name and it should work. Also post urls.py in the question.

Comment: use  from django.conf.urls import include

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
                             ^^^^^^^
urlpatterns = [
# ... snip ...
url(r'^community/', include('django_website.aggregator.urls')),
url(r'^contact/', include('django_website.contact.urls')),
# ... snip ...
]
```

So, for the little explanation:

When you try to run your program, the problem is that the word "include" is not defined anywhere. To solve this situation, you need to define that word and since this is a function from django.conf.urls is as simple as import it at the beginning from your file.

Hope it helps, here is a bit of docs that may help you understand a bit more about django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/

Comment: /*Hey! thanks. but after importing include I'm getting the following error. By the way, I am using Django1.11.4*/

 File "C:\Users\Rohan Jain\venvi\blog\urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.url import url
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.conf.url'

/* Apart from this I'm getting exceptions in mysite/urls.py and the other exceptions as mentioned in the question asked.*/

Comment: the correct name is django.conf.url**s**  this is a good starting point https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ hope it helps